# Load the parameters into javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my uploaded JQ scripts

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
```

and my php code

```
  echo '<div id="zakazat" onclick="GetOrder('.$row['title'].')">Заказать!</div>';
```

title have is string value : "test 1"

my simple js code

```
function GetOrder(param1){
alert(param1);
    };
```

In the my function have error in FireBug with text:
"
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    GetOrder(test 1)"

hov fix task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using jQuery. You can try this.

Store your data in custom `data-*` prefixed attributes

```
<div id="order" data-param="test 1">click me!</div>
```

Bind click event like

```
$("#order").on('click', function(){
    var param1 = $(this).data('param'); //Fetch data using .data()
    GetOrder(param1);
});
```

---

You have to pass string parameter in quotes `''`

```
<div id="order" onclick="GetOrder('test 1')">click me!</div>
```

Comment: please check the question again

Comment: @lails, did you tried jquery way. Just pass value using cutom attributes

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to pass a string You have to do like below

```
<div id="order" onclick="GetOrder('test 1')">click me!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<div id="order" onclick="GetOrder('test 1')">click me!</div>
```